# Angular - CSS Grid - Align columns by index

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to make a css grid in which there are 4 columns, and infinite rows. What I'd like to do is have the text-align property (or maybe a grid alignment property?) on the first column to be 'start', middle 2 columns to be 'center', and the last to be 'end'. All of the content in the grid is being created with an ngFor, iterating over an array, and storing the index in a variable, like so:

```html
<div class="expander-content">
  <p *ngFor="let service of location.services; let i = index" [ngStyle]="{'text-align': getTextAlign(i)} ">{{service.name}}</p>
</div>
```

The scss for my expander-content is written as below:

```css
.expander-content{
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

And finally, the getTextAlign() function:

```js
getTextAlign(index: number): string {
  if (index !== 0 && index % 3 === 0) return 'end';
  else if (index !== 0 && (index % 2 === 0 || index % 2 === 1)) return 'center';
  else return 'start';
}
```

As you can see, what I originally thought was to take the index of each item and determinine a text-align based off of the modulo of the index. The math is definitely off, and you're more than welcome to help with that if you'd like! But, my main question is, is there a better way to achieve this with css grid? I've googled and the best answer only uses 3 columns, and doesn't exactly work with my current situation. I'm pretty rusty with css grid, but I'd assume I'm most likely trying to achieve this the hard way. Short of trying to skim through a course to find exactly what I need, I thought I'd ask on here.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I think it makes sense that you'd need the getTextAlign function to figure out whether an item is first, last or other in the grid.

Comment: @KatinkaHesselink Thanks for the reply! that does make sense. I suppose I just have to get my math right. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't making things harder on myself lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by, instead, just creating a string[] in my component class and iterating over the services[] array once the subscription is made to the object:

```js
private alignments = new Array<string>();

//and, upon subscription

let counter = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < this.location.services.length; i++) {
  if (counter === 0) this.alignments.push('start');
  else if (counter === 1 || counter === 2) this.alignments.push('center');
  else {
    this.alignments.push('end');
    counter = 0;
    continue;
   }
   counter++;
}

//and finally, get the alignment:
getTextAlign(index: number): string {
  return this.alignments[index];
}
```

I could probably do a better job at creating the array with something like Map(), instead of a for loop, but the jest of it is there. I still haven't given up on using modulo, so I'll revisit this later if I find the answer to that!